# Is there any way to sync the iphone 4S with a mac running OS v10.4.11?

Tags: sync, itunes, osx-tiger

The iphone 4S system requirements state that you need a Mac running: OS X v10.5.8 to be able to sync an iphone 4S with itunes, but I'm looking for a work around. Patches, hacks or whatever it takes to make it work.
**The assumption is that the MAC OSX cannot be upgraded, but software can be installed on it.**
If the phone can't be syncd with itunes, I'm willing to look at alternative programs.

So my question again
**Is there any way to sync the iphone 4S with a mac running OS v10.4.11?**

Comment: Just in case the reason here is that you have a PowerPC based Mac: They are able to run OS X 10.5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I asked this Q on behalf of a friend. From what I understand they aren't able to upgrade. Not sure of the reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone 4S requires at least iTunes 10.5, which requires Mac OS X Leopard, not Tiger because of all the new APIs Apple has put in the newer operating systems.

There are plenty of software that can totally replace iTunes + iPod, but not iPhone or even iPod touch, since Application can't be installed through those third-party software, also the Contacts, Calendar, Emails can't be synced. It would be foolish to not use iTunes.

I'm sorry that it is not what you wanted to hear, since your description include "not going to upgrade" and "use an iTunes alternative". But there is really no good way to do that.

There are more iTunes alternative for Windows than for Macs. You may have better chance using BootCamp. But that will be even more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Bootcamp might be an option, but I've heard it's hard to get hold of (at least for 10.4.11).